# Docker extra_hosts not pointing to localhost server

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, hosts

I am learning docker, and I was wondering if I could point to a domain that points to localhost the same way one would edit their hosts file. I saw that I could use `extra_hosts` which I thought was supposed to do this. However, it doesn't point to my server `http://127.0.0.1/` it points to an already existing server when I navigate to `http://example.com`. If I point my browser to `http://127.0.0.1`, then the browser displays `hi` (as seen in the app below), so I know the app works.

I have this in my `yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: "node:14"
    extra_hosts:
      - "example.com:127.0.0.1"
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    command: "npm start"
```

I am not sure if it matters what command I am using but I am using this:

```
docker-compose up
```

The application is super simple, all it is, is a server that prints out `hi`:

```js
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.write('hi')
  res.end()
}).listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on port 8080'))
```

**Edit:**

Looking at `/etc/hosts` in the container, I do see the value in there:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

Is there any way I can get that added to the **Host Machine's** `hosts` file instead of the **container**?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do... a) do you want to access your app when typing http://example.com on your browser? or b) do you want to access your host machine when using example.com from inside the container?

Comment: I am trying to do option "a"

Comment: In that case you need to edit the `/etc/hosts` file in **your** machine and not in your container. The *extra_hosts* option edits the `/etc/hosts` file in the container.

Comment: Correct, so, my question is, can this be done in the `yaml` file to edit the **Host** machine hosts file?

Comment: You could mount your /etc/hosts file in a container and let it modify it. But this seems way more complicated than just simply editing the file yourself.